# Hot to get the posts that belongs to users that other user follows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables `users`, `follow`, `posts`
**Users Table**

```
id
...
```

**Follow Table**

```
user_id
designer_id
```

**Posts Table**

```
user_id
...
```

How to get the posts from the designers that user follows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `hasManyThrough` which provides access to distant relations via an intermediate relation.

Define relationship as follow:

User Model

```
 /**
 * Get all of the posts of followed users.
 */
public function followedPosts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
                  Post::class,
                  Follow::class,
                  'user_id',
                  'user_id',
                  'id',
                  'designer_id');
}
```